# h5 file open error despite using the absolute path of the file or placing the data file in the working directory

Tags: file, hdf5

I have a directory that contains all the h5 data files. I started with one of them for calculations. The code I had worked fine to read that file. However, when I used the same code to read a different data file in the very same directory, I got the following error message:

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'N.2019-06.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)"

When I got this error message, I placed the data file 'N.2019-06.h5' in my working directory. I also tried with an absolute path for the fie and got the same error message.

I googled the internet for ways to deal with the problem. Those are the two ways, i.e., using an absolute path for the file or placing it in the working directory, I found but neither worked for me.

Then I simply used three lines as follows to try to read the data file and got the same error message:

```
import h5py
infile = f"N.2019-06.h5"    
f1 = h5py.File(infile,'r')
```

However, if I changed the infile to the very first file I read, it worked. Is there any other way that I am not aware of to deal with this problem? BTW, I encountered the problem in Jupyter, and then I ran the code in Spider and had the same error message. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You have a problem somewhere with your working directory or filename. Use glob package to check contents of the current directory. Code: `import glob; h5_files = glob.glob('*.h5'); print(h5_files)`. h5_files will be a list of all files that match the *.h5 wildcard in the current directory. Good luck.

Comment: kcw78: Thank you so much! Something was off with the extensions of the other files which was hidden. Many thanks again!